# Finite sequence length before and after removing repetitions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a sequence $S$ of length $n^3+1$  where the elements are not necessarily distinct and every element appears at most $n$ times. Why does the sequence $S'$ where I remove all repetitions from $S$ have at least $n^2+1$ elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If the length of sequence $S$ were $n^3$ and all terms were repeated exactly $n$ times, then you would have exactly $n^2$ distinct terms.

Comment: Oh I see, it was not clear to me that the extreme case of having every element repeated $n$ times was possible. Thank you